# Android Service: Unable to start service intent { act=edu.darts.neuromobi.TestService }: not found

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I have the same problem others have had, but I can't get my code to work.

I have to java classes, Test.java and TestService.java and when I try to start Service or bind Service, I always get error listed above.  I have tried the recommended standard solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8359786/633182), but it didn't work. I will try to rename the java files and start a new project to see if that works as noted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052978/unable-to-start-service-intent).

Then I saw this [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) by Vogella that I have to have a google user registered on the device.  Is that what my problem is or am I confusing the errors (maybe 'intent.REGISTER' refers to something else).

Any suggestions on this will be greatly appreciated.

> 4.3. Register your application
>
> Run your application, maintain your registered user and press the
>   button. Check LogCat for the registration ID.
>
> If you see the following message:
>
> " Unable to start service Intent
>   {act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER ... }: not found"

I've tried this, both on my phone and on the simulator.

Permissions:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/gyroscopic" android:label="@string/app_name">
...
<activity android:name="Test"></activity>

<service android:name="TestService"></service>  
....
</application>
```

Comment: WC, we are here to collaborate and help each other :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the entire package code for your service, that's what I always do and it has always worked so far.

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name="com.mobowski.appfrag.service.MusicService" >
</service>
```

---

Edit for starting / binding to the service.

I usually do this:

**Starting the service**

```
// This is in the onCreate of my main screen, but this would work in a button
startService(
            new Intent(this, Service.class));
```

**In the service itself**

You will use this when binding to the service

```
// Field of service
private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder(); 

// We return the binder class upon a call of bindService
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }
```

**Binding to the service**

For this I use several pieces of code that I took from an example once but they never failed me so far.

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            s = ((MusicService.MyBinder) binder).getService();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            // Little Toast to make sure we connected

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            s = null;
        }
    };

    void doBindService() {
        bindService(
            new Intent(this,
                    MusicService.class), mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
```

Comment: Like I said above, there are many related posts I've read (but I'm not saying that I read them all-- there are many) that suggest the same issue and it doesn't work (here is what I have in my manifest):`... <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".AccelerometerService"></service> <activity android:name="TremCam"></activity> </application>`

Comment: Question. How are you trying to start / bind to the service?

Comment: Binding to the services is done by:`Intent i = new Intent(AccelerometerService.class.getName());  
          bindService(i, _connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);  
          _isBound = true;`

Comment: Starting the _service_ (when the button is clicked):`//Intent i = new Intent(AccelerometerService.class.getName());  
Intent i = new Intent("edu.nd.bitstorm.AccelerometerService");  
this.startService(i);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the namespace in the name attribute in some form so:

```
<service android:name="edu.darts.neuromobi.TestService"></service>
```

or possibly:

```
<service android:name=".TestService"></service>
```

Comment: Thank you @Vimal for fixing my post, I will do that next time.

Comment: I've seen your suggestion in many of the other related posts, but I get the same result!  I even tried to just take the service and the activity (that uses push-buttons to start the or bind to the service) and put them in a new project and with different file names with the same result.