# Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.UserLogin/.BgService (has extras) }: not found

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm trying to start a service using Alarmmanager with pendingIntent. I stuck with `Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.UserLogin/.BgService (has extras) }: not found`
 error i've googled and searched in stackoverflow seen some questions about this error but those solutions are not worked with me. [StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265020/why-doesnt-my-service-work-in-android-i-just-want-to-log-something-ever-5-sec), [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052978/unable-to-start-service-intent), Please check this once.

Service Class:

```
public class BgService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("OnStart");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("OnStartcmd");
       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, 10);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.UserLogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <application></application>
    <service android:name="com.UserLogin.BgService" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name="com.UserLogin.MyActivity" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /></manifest>
```

java class

```
 Intent myIn1tent = new Intent(UserLogin.this, BgService.class);
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(UserLogin.this, 0, myIn1tent , 0);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, 30 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Logcat Error:

```
03-29 14:30:47.337: W/ActivityManager(58): Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.UserLogin/.BgService (has extras) }: not found
```

Comment: Do you put <service> tag inside <application> tag, and how about package name in manifest file

Comment: Updated androidmanifest.xml in question. service tag is not inside application tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your service declaration in manifest must be  nested in application tag like this..

```
<application>
<service android:name="" />
</application>
```

and yeah... how can your activity be outside of your application tag.. :|

Comment: +1, My friends got an funny issue before by typing <Service> instead of <service>, it seem ADT team need a little update to avoid something like that