# Service doesnt start

Tags: android, service

in the below code i am trying to start a service as shown. but at run time

```
serviceCtrl.isMyServiceRunning()
```

returns false and the toast doesnt show up despite the service is added to the manifest file.

i am starting the service wrongly?! why the service does not start

**code**:

```
if (mIsBonded) {
            mSB.append("Pairing Completed" + "\n");
            Intent intSPPService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SPPService.class);
            intSPPService.putExtra("key", "starting SPP Service");
            startService(intSPPService);

            ServiceCtrl serviceCtrl = new ServiceCtrl(getApplicationContext(), ActMain.class);
            if (serviceCtrl.isMyServiceRunning()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting SPP Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //mATRFCConn = new ATRFCConn();
            //mATRFCConn.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            mSB.append("Pairing Failed" + "\n");
        }
...
...
...

public boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.mCtx.getSystemService(this.mCtx.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (this.mClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**service**:

```
public class SPPService extends Service {

private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
final static String SPP_SERVICE_ACTION = "SPP_ACTION";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.w(TAG, "onCreate");

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onStartCommand");

    String str = intent.getStringExtra("key");
    Log.v(TAG, "Act->Service : " + str);


    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

**Update**

at run time i receive

```
 W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { 
 cmp=com.example.com.myapplication/com.example.com.servicebt_01.SPPService 
 (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

**manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.com.servicebt_01" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".ActMain" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".SPPService"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/service_name"
    >
</service>
```

Comment: Did the log `onCreate` in `onCreate` of service be invoked?

Comment: @FireSun no it did not

Comment: And are you sure `startService(intSPPService);` has been invoked?
`

Comment: @FireSun yes as shown in the code posted above...please also have a look at the update section..there is a warning msg i receive in the logcat

Comment: It is possible your service is running but Toast Object is Expired so Use Static Toast Object and Check

Comment: Surely its about the name you have given in manifest file

Comment: @rahul please have alook at the manifest file posted above#

Comment: I think you need to add a '.' in front of the name.  android:name=".SPPService". try this

Comment: Maybe you'd better paste your `Manifest` file here and your path of  `SSPService` in project.

Comment: @FireSun  i found it..i should have declared the service inside the application tag of the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer :
[Unable to start service Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052978/unable-to-start-service-intent)

It says you have not given the name of the service in the manifest correctly. Please verify it.

Try to enter the Service name along with the entire package name in which it is present.

Answer (score 0):

Your service name in manifest is error,not

```
<service
android:name="SPPService"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/service_name"
>
</service>
```

If your `SSPService` is located in your application package,you can specify it like this:

```
<service
android:name=".SPPService"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/service_name"
>
</service>
```

If not,you should specify its full path.

Comment: Try use full path of  `SSPService`,maybe this class doesn't located in your package directly.

Comment: it is in located in the package directly